# Magento 2: How to make custom fee taxable

Tags: magento2, addtocart, tax, quoteitem, grand-total

- I want to add a tax on custom fee. tax calculation is perfect and gets tax amount but it's not set in TAX files in quote_address in the database.

  ```
  public function collect(
      \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
      \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
      \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
  ){

    $total->setTaxAmount($total->getTaxAmount()+$taxAmount);
    $total->setBaseTaxAmount($total->getBaseTaxAmount()+$taxAmount); 
  }
  ```
- I try to set tax Amount in collect method but it's not set.
- I want to same like this [thiscode.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4300/how-to-make-custom-fee-taxable) it's Magento1 but I want Magento 2

Comment: Try to follow the following to add custom fee to your subtotal https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2/93349

Answer (score 1):

You may please use below code to set tax amount in quote address and quote tables:

```
$quote->setTaxAmount($total->getTaxAmount() + $taxAmount);
$quote->setBaseTaxAmount($total->getBaseTaxAmount() + $taxAmount);

$address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
$address->setTaxAmount($total->getTaxAmount() + $taxAmount);
$address->setBaseTaxAmount($total->getBaseTaxAmount() + $taxAmount);
```

I hope this help to you. If you have any further query feel free to ask.

Happy to help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a call to `$total->setTaxAmount()` you need to use `addTotalAmount`:

```
$total->addTotalAmount('tax', $amount);
$total->addBaseTotalAmount('tax', $baseAmount);
```